# How to get HDD serial number in python using Dual Bay Docking Station?

Tags: python, drive, hard-drive, serial-number

When I'm using python to get HDD serial number

```python
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
for x in c.Win32_PhysicalMedia():
  print(x)
```

function returns:

```python
{
  SerialNumber = "00000000000000000000";
  Tag = "\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE1";
};
```

HDD D: is connected using a dual bay docking station
But c's serial number connected directly to my pc looks good.
Is there any way to get this info using python?

Comment: Could you show the code you use to obtain HDD serial number in Python?

Comment: `import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for x in c.Win32_PhysicalMedia():
    print(x)`

Comment: I'd have thought you'll need to interrogate the FW on the dock.